# my code runs before I press the button

Tags: javascript, button, react-native

I have an issue regarding my code. To run the algorithms, 
I created a button and I expect it to run after I press it, 
but what happens is that the algorithms run 
and then the button functions and displays return value.The whole algorithm is inside of the Demopipeline.js. Any ideas??

```ts
import...
const demoPipeline = require('./gaitApp/src/apps/Demopipline');

export default class runAlgos extends Component {
    async try () {
        const newRun = await demoPipeline.run();
        console.log('this is:  ');
        console.log(newRun);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                    Welcome to React Native!
                </Text>
                <Button
                    color='yellowgreen'
                    title="Run Demopipeline"
                    onPress={this.try.bind(this)}
                />

            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that the code inside `demoPipeline.run()` runs? Is the tow `console.log`s run too?

Comment: what I expect here is only to execute the try function and see some results in console, but before i press the button it executes the demopipeline, doesnt returns anything, and after pressing the button it executes everything again and returns what I want. I dont want it to do anything before I press the button, though

Answer (score 1):

This pattern should work:

```
class runAlgos extends Component {

    let try = async () => {
        // ..
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button
                    title=".."
                    onPress={this.try}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Also you can use the following:

```
<Button title=".." onPress={() => this.try()} />
```

With

```
async try () {
    //..
}
```

But it is a bad practice (performance hit, since the onPress will create a *new* function on every re-render)

Comment: Try `const` or `var`, but `let` works completely fine on mine

Comment: i dont know but in my case declaring with var, let ,const throws an error

Comment: And if you remove all to keep it as `try = () => ..` would it work? take into consideration that it will become a global variable

Comment: try should be a function not a variable, onpress requires a function to call, therefore it doesnt accept let,var or let, or? because what I want to create is function namely 'try', thanks anyways :)

Comment: @cancan When you write `var try = () => { /* .. */ }` then `try` is a function and not just a variable. Read [**some basics**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and good luck

Comment: I lately realized that the cause of this was due to some function inside the Demopipeline.js, so your code was helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use your function like this to solve this problem:

```
try = async () => {
    const newRun = await demoPipeline.run();
    console.log('this is:  ');
    console.log(newRun);
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                Welcome to React Native!
            </Text>
            <Button
                color='yellowgreen'
                title="Run Demopipeline"
                onPress={this.try}
            />

        </View>
    );
}
```

And you don't need to bind functions if define them as an arrow function.

Comment: what you say could be true in case of the design of the code but it doesnt change the result, it still executes everything before I press the button, but thanks :)

Comment: you  use the `onPress={this.try}` and your code execute before you press the button again?

Comment: yes that' the issue, i cant call it "again" because it does this 'first', when I press the button it run again actually

Comment: I tested it again and it works well if you use the `try` function like this `onPress={this.try}` this wont run before you press the button.